# Creating AD-Users from VBScript -> Error Code 0

Tags: vbscript, active-directory

I am running into a strange error in VBScript:

```
[...]
            objUser.sAMAccountName = strNTName
            On Error Resume Next
            objUser.SetInfo
            If (Err.Number <> 0) Then
                On Error GoTo 0
                Wscript.Echo "Unable to create user with NT name: " & strNTName & " - Error-Code: " & Err.Number & " (sAMAccountName)"
            Else
[...]
```

Well I get a message box:
Unable to create user with NT name: testuser - Error-Code: 0 (sAMAccountName)

How can that happen? What am I doing wrong?
Is 0 <> 0?!?
Also tried "0" to be sure...

---

Update:
Now - thanks to @JosefZ I sorted out the Error code -2147016651
But that does not help me eigther...
New Code:

```
[...]
    Set objUser = objContainer.Create("user", "cn=" & strCN)
    If (Err.Number <> 0) Then
        On Error GoTo 0
        Wscript.Echo "Unable to create user with cn: " & strCN
    Else
        On Error GoTo 0
        ' Assign mandatory attributes and save user object.
        If (strNTName = "") Then
            strNTName = strCN
        End If
            objUser.sAMAccountName = strNTName
            On Error Resume Next
            objUser.SetInfo
            If (Err.Number <> 0) Then
                Wscript.Echo "Unable to create user with NT name: " & strNTName & " - Error-Code: " & Err.Number & " (sAMAccountName)"
                On Error GoTo 0
            Else
[...]
```

strNTName is testuser (no spaces - checked that)

strCN is 'Test User' (no other chars before or after and without the quotes of course)

Comment: updated information. Now getting error  -2147016651

Comment: Add `Wscript.Echo err.source, err.description`

Comment: @JosefZ just getting an emtpy message box with your line (Next line after ...<> 0) Then). Also tried Err.Description (seems the best variant in my eyes) and Err.description

Comment: `VBScript` commands, statements, variable names etc. are case insensitive. However, I consider your original question answered. For error code `-2147016651` ask another question (best at http://serverfault.com/ _imho_). Add output from `Wscript.Echo err.number & vbNewLine & err.source & vbNewLine & err.description & vbNewLine & Hex(err.number)` there. Don't forget this `echo` needs to _precede_ any (even implicit) `err.clear`

Comment: Resolved this also: It was a problem in my infrastructure... It was a Test-Copy of my 2003 DC. On a Win7-Client it showed "The server cannot compute your request" (translated DE->EN). I was not able to solve but I then ran it in our live environment using snapshots as backup and it worked correctly. I guess it was missing something. (we have 3 DCs, 2 DNS live and test was onle a DC and a Client with lmhosts and hosts entrys)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Poorly documented that `On Error GoTo 0` statement calls the `Clear` method automatically. Therefore, use

```
'[...]
        objUser.sAMAccountName = strNTName
        On Error Resume Next
        objUser.SetInfo
        If (Err.Number <> 0) Then
            Wscript.Echo "Unable to create user with NT name: " & strNTName & " - Error-Code: " & Err.Number & " (sAMAccountName)"
            On Error GoTo 0
        Else
'[...]
```

Comment: Thanks! Now I get error -2147016651 which is not really helpful, too. I'll edit my question